# Проблема с компиляцией классов в Web maven проекте.

Tags: maven, веб-программирование, java

Есть такой проект
(прототип мавена - стандартный для Web app, апач мавен веб апп, так вроде)
[image]

У меня есть два класса.
В обоих по одному полю int. C одним нормально собирает War проект и деплои в Tomcat, а
с другим выдает ошибку.
Все по порядку.

Классы

```
public class mysuperclass   
         {
          public int a = 5;
         }

public class qw   {
           public int a = 5;
           }
```

Ошибка:
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project test80: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre7..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке гласит, что не найден путь к компилятору. Так что не очень понятно, как у вас вообще что-то компилировалось.

Comment: В других проектах все нормально. Вот еще вопрос тогда в кучу, я тут самовольно добавил папку java в папку resources, могло это порушить прототип?
Если да, то посоветуйте прототип для web приложений, где я могу нормально добавить свой сервлет.

Comment: @alex91 Перечитайте мой первый комментарий и сообщение об ошибке еще раз. Затем настройте окружение и/или IDE и все будет хорошо.